# Can I move the div object from one browser to another browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two questions about the HTML and Javascript, I'm really appreciate any answer.

1. Can I move the div object (include all the elements inside it) in the same browser ( like IE9, or FF) but difference widows? 
   Example: I have two firefox windows, one contain the div and it's elements (W1), and another is blank (W2). So, I wanna drag the div from the W1 to W2 and the div must display like in W1. Is it possible to do that?
2. Can I move the div object (include all the element inside the div) from one browser ( like firefox 10) to another browser (like IE9)?
   Example: like the above example, but different browsers ( one window is ff, and another is IE) is it possible to do?

Comment: HTML5 drag and drop, when mature, will allow you to do this.

Comment: @AtesGoral I doubt it. Moving content between (unrelated) browser windows is a serious safety policy violation. Drag and drop will only work inside one window.

Comment: @freakish How about only if they are from the same domain? Same Origin Policy could apply to cross-browser drag and drops.

Comment: @AtesGoral Sure, it sounds okay. Still a bit strange. :) We need to wait and see.

Comment: @freakish Strange, yes. And probably unnecessary, too :)

Answer (score 2):

Long story short:

ad 1) It is possible if the first window has a reference to the other (see javascript `window.open`).

ad 2) Impossible,

Comment: Even (1) is only possible if both windows belong to the same domain.

Comment: Read the question - thangpt said that the other window is blank.

Comment: thank you, freakish, you're right, i have tried many times with the blank window, but it's seem impossible

Comment: While it is possible, it doesn't mean it's simple. You need to make sure to transfer the div to the other document using [adoptNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.adoptNode). Maybe ask a separate question on the detailed implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can do this if you have a reference to the other window.
2) You could transmit the div back to the server, and re-display it in the other window in the same way. Otherwise, there's no way to transfer divs browsers using javascript alone.

Comment: If they're two windows of the same browser instance, you could potentially use session cookies to avoid a round trip to the server.

Comment: can you explain to me more clear about your idea? thank you very much

Comment: 1> yes, you're right, we can do it if I have a reference to the other window. ( in this case, my reference is the function to listen the drag event of window).
2> In my case, I just use pure javascript to do that, don't have any process on server.But thank you, I will investigate this solution. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, my idea is I have one page with the content. (some thing like <div id=contentid>...</div>) and I open this page in firefox browser, then I'm keeping open another window (maybe firefox or another like crome, or safari, or IE9)..Then, I wanna copy the content to the new window by click on the div, then drag it into new window, drop, then the new window will display the same content as the first window.

Answer (score 0):

I have take a look on the internet, and It's seem impossible to do that with the blank window. 
But without blank window ( i mean, the prepared window) we can do it.

Example: Open two links below in the same browser but different window, or different browsers, then try to move the objects (in this case are the pictures) from a window to another (with the same browser or different). You can see it can get the transformed data.

http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/overview/DataTransferOverviewEX.htm

http://www.useragentman.com/tests/dragAndDrop/05b-crossFrameSetData/